# Xampp files not showing up

Tags: php, xampp

I'm using Xampp no problem. I normally type localhost/assignment2 and the list of php pages I created come up but I just created an index.php page and now when I type localhost/assignment2 the index page is showing instead of my list a programs I made.

Is there a way I can rectify this or do I need to do something specific to it.

Comment: Rename the index page to something else. index files will be served by default.

Comment: rename your index file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You server will always search for index.php, index.html and index.htm in your folder and show it if it exists. If none of these files exists the server shows a list of all files or an error, depending on your configuration.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because there is conflict between the name of xamp's index.php and the index.php that you have created.The same problem will arise if you create **home.php.** By default xamp gives preference to the index.php file and instead of showing the index of files it ends up displaying index.php. So the solution is to change your index.php filename to index1.php .